# Mapping array data in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am currently learning react and I want to display the data of a subarray i.e it is an array as a values of property , and I want to display it to the user . Since I am new I don't know how to do this , I did like this but I get this error

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const User = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();

    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        name: "",
        username: "",
        email: "",
        actions: []
    });

    const [action, setAction] = useState({
        actionName: "",
        actionContribution: "",
        actionDescription: ""
    });

    const loadUser = async () => {
        const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3003/users/${id}`);
        setUser(res.data);
        res.data.actions.map(action => {
            setAction(action);
        })
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        loadUser();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Link className="btn btn-primary" to="/">Back to Home</Link>
            <div className="row col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">
                <div className="card">
                    <div className="card-header">
                        <h1 className="card-title">Member Id:{id}</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <dl className="row">
                            <dt className="col-6">Name :</dt>
                            <dd className="col-6">{user.name}</dd>
                            <dt className="col-6">UserName :</dt>
                            <dd className="col-6">{user.username}</dd>
                            <dt className="col-6">Email :</dt>
                            <dd className="col-6">{user.email}</dd>
                            <dd> {action.actionName} </dd>
                            <dt className="col-6">Website</dt>
                            <dd className="col-6">{user.website}</dd>
                        </dl>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default User;
```

The error is get is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'actionName' of null
```

How should i solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you are using setAction without checking if the action object is defined or if there are all properties that you rely on.

I updated you code with a suggest, that uses destructuring before assigning and set a default that helps you to indicate a missing property.

Question

Do you really want to use a map function to loop through all of your action entries and override them, instead of selection directly the last one?

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const User = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();

    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        name: "",
        username: "",
        email: "",
        actions: []
    });

    const loadUser = async () => {
        const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3003/users/${id}`);

        const {
            name = "",
            username = "",
            email = "",
            actions = []
        } = res.data || {};

        const filteredActions = actions.filter((action) =>{
          return (action !== undefined && action !== null && action instanceof Object);
        });

        setUser({ name, username, email, actions: filteredActions });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        loadUser();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Link className="btn btn-primary" to="/">Back to Home</Link>
            <div className="row col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">
                <div className="card">
                    <div className="card-header">
                        <h1 className="card-title">Member Id:{id}</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <dl className="row">
                            <dt className="col-6">Name :</dt>
                            <dd className="col-6">{user.name}</dd>
                            <dt className="col-6">UserName :</dt>
                            <dd className="col-6">{user.username}</dd>
                            <dt className="col-6">Email :</dt>
                            <dd className="col-6">{user.email}</dd>
                            <dd>{user.actions.map((action) => {
                                const {
                                    actionName = 'no name',
                                    actionContribution = 'no contribution',
                                    actionDescription = 'no description'
                                } = action;
                                return `${actionName} - ${actionContribution} - ${actionDescription}`;
                            })} </dd>
                            <dt className="col-6">Website</dt>
                            <dd className="col-6">{user.website}</dd>
                        </dl>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default User;
```

Comment: I want to display all the actions , like action.actionName etc etc of all the actions

Comment: @Sanket, than i would suggest you to use a your setter to add all of your actions to it and use a map function in your jsx render method.

Comment: @Sanket, i updated the code suggest, it should be obsolete to use the second setter `setAction` because you have already saved all actions in the user state object.
I added also a map function to the rendering method for demonstration. Maybe this should work for you.

Comment: What if there are null objects in the array , what was the earlier code for that , how to not display that

Comment: Do you mean that one? https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63800517/2
You can use a filter function instead to remove null values

Comment: @Sanket check the new filtered actions ;)

Comment: Yess , this was helpfull , i had error because of null items , this worked ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

action is not readily available in state..Hence it is causing the error.

```
{action && <dd> { action.actionName } </dd>}
```